# How do I set default Action for Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

So I have 2 controller:

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
public class ItemController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public LinkedList<Object> FindItem([FromUri]ItemQuery query) {
        ....
    }
}
```

And

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
public class SubDepController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public LinkedList<Object> FindSubDep(string ID) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Here is the thing, I try to call both:

```
http://localhost:43751/api/SubDep

http://localhost:43751/api/Item
```

And the Item Controller works but the SubDep does not work!  Why is that?

Here is my WebApiConfig:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "withAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

The error I get back is this:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:43751/api/SubDep'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'SubDep' that matches the request."}
```

---

BONUS question:

How does ASP.NET MVC know that I try to hit:

```
http://localhost:43751/api/Item
```

It automatically go to the FindItem Action?  It's like pure MAGIC to me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to call `FindSubDep` action, your query string should be like belwo:

```
http://localhost:43751/api/SubDep/1
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, this is the reason.  I made the parameter optional and it's calling the function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For the bonus question. It gets to the correct action because of the HTTP verb [GET] in your case, when you make a GET request for

```
http://localhost:43751/api/Item
```

it will find an action with [HttpGet] attribute on Item controller.